# python program gets KILLED with no errors during csv phare

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to convert a csv file from comma delimited to Pipe delimited.  Reason why i am not using comma delimited is because i am taking this file and import it mysql database.  some fields have a comma in it itself, so hence when i import using comma delimited the filed that data is getting imported into is changing, so i am running the below python script to change it from comma to pipe...so that when i import the data the comma itself remain where it needs to be and i import using PIPE delimiter... but for some reason it is failing, one thing to keep in mind it, this exact thing works just fine last month when the file was about 400MB, not its about 600MB

```
[root@host Dec]# python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Dec  8 2015, 18:25:23)
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import csv
>>>
>>> with open('/root/Dec/dec_no_quotes.csv', 'rb') as fin, \
...     open('/root/Dec/dec_pipe.txt', 'wb') as fout:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(fin)
...     writer = csv.DictWriter(fout, reader.fieldnames, delimiter='|')
...     writer.writeheader()
...     writer.writerows(reader)
...
Killed
[root@host Dec]#
```

Here is the out of memory messaged found thru dmseg...

[1710282.264394] Out of memory: Kill process 22798 (python) score 861 or sacrifice child
[1710282.269487] Killed process 22798 (python) total-vm:1954188kB, anon-rss:1818208kB, file-rss:176kB

Comment: Probably the linux out of memory killer. Check `dmesg` to confirm that.

Comment: @DavidMaust, Yeap looks like that was it... Now another question is, this system has 2GB of memory and looking at free command it shows i have 1400MB free, why does a that is 600MB in size, need a more memory than 1400mb free ?

Comment: It is understandable that the size could increase when reading the files into memory since you are creating dict objects out of them with their field names present. The more important question though seems to be, why isn't it just reading one record and writing a record. It should not be loading the entire file into memory using `DictReader`, should it?

Comment: @DavidMaust I just looked at `csv.py` and surprisingly, that's almost exactly what it does.... the whole thing is converted to a list and then sent to be base writer. The non-dict writer is written in C and appears to be sane. So, the solution should be to use use `reader` and `writer` instead of `DictReader` and `DictWriter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly, `DictWriter` converts rows to a list and then calls the low level writer. From the 2.x source...

```
def writerows(self, rowdicts):
    rows = []
    for rowdict in rowdicts:
        rows.append(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
    return self.writer.writerows(rows)
```

Since you don't use column names, there is no good reason for using `DictWriter`, which is slower and as seen above, not very scalable. Just use the base writer instead.

```
>>> with open('/root/Dec/dec_no_quotes.csv', 'rb') as fin, \
...     open('/root/Dec/dec_pipe.txt', 'wb') as fout:
...     reader = csv.reader(fin)
...     writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter='|')
...     writer.writerows(reader)
...
```